# Can't install "meld"

Tags: package-management, git, diff

I'm trying to install `meld` on Ubuntu (I use VirtualBox on Windows 7) in order to visualize `git diff`:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

But, it doesn't succeed:

```
...
Get:9 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main python-pyorbit i386 2.24.0-6ubuntu1 [92.4 kB]
Get:10 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main python-gnome2 i386 2.28.1-3 [361 kB]
Get:11 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe python-gtksourceview2 i386 2.10.1-2 [131 kB]
Fetched 1,310 kB in 6s (214 kB/s)                                             
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-2_i386.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/meld/meld_1.5.2-1ubuntu2_all.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pyorbit/python-pyorbit_2.24.0-6ubuntu1_i386.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-python/python-gnome2_2.28.1-3_i386.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtksourceview/python-gtksourceview2_2.10.1-2_i386.deb Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What could be the problem, and how could I install `meld` properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try what it says in the last line:

> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe **run apt-get update** or try with **--fix-missing**?

Comment: Thanks! `sudo apt-get install meld --fix-missing` solved the problem.